# Django model structure in my project

Tags: database, django, django-models

I'm creating a text-based browser game and need some advice for django model structure. All the examples are from the same project, therefore I will not repeat the same information assuming you've read all the questions from the top to the bottom.

---

**First question**

I have an `auth` app which contains user profile (`Player` model), `alliance` app which holds information about all the unions players join and `medals` app which represents rewards for both players and alliances.

Both users and alliances can have medals assigned so one of the options is to create a M2M field in `Player` and `Alliance` models linking to `Medal`.

Another option would make `medals` app usable in any other project of mine. This approach includes the use of generic relations in `Medal` model which links to either `Player` or `Alliance`.

Which solution is more django-like or can I do however I want to?

---

**Second question**

There will be tasks for players to accomplish. The scenarios of tasks vary greatly, therefore I need some kind of approach to write unique task progress checking code for each task.

Tasks are held in the database containing information about rewards (which are pretty much the same). Where should I write unique code for each task? Maybe I should add some fields and eval() them later? Then all the information will be held in the DB.

Moreover, tasks demand some tracking, for example, imagine a simple task of going to the manual section (just to make sure the player knows where it is). Then I need to register somewhere whether the player has visited manual page or not. I think about creating another model `TaskTrackers` in task app. Then another question arises. If I should add OneToOne field from `Player` to `TaskTrackers` or vice versa?

---

To sum up, the main question is whether should I add OneToOneFields/M2M fields to user profile model or add OneToOneFields/Foreigneys from target models to User model? The latter would make my apps more reusable, but the first approach may be more logical.

Waiting for answers.

Comment: BTW, it isn't a good idea to call an app "auth" if you are going to use Django authentication. It is also caled `auth`, and two apps with same name isn't very good (e.g. `manage.py test auth`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One your first question, you could do either an M2M to Medal, or use a generic foreign key. You'll end up with a couple of join tables with M2M. With the generic foreign key, you won't have any join tables, but you will have the extra query for the content type. So, you may need to set up both ways and see which is going to impact performance more

On your second question, I might take the approach of using a "Task" model with one or more "Step" models that can be set up as an inline formset. Then you'll need a table like "CompletedPlayerTasks" or something like that, which contains the Player ID, Task ID and Step ID. If a Step ID exists in that table, the task has been completed.

It sounds like you need to be able to create custom fields and forms for the Steps of each Task, which isn't terribly hard to do in Django. There are [some off the shelf solutions](http://archisman.posterous.com/creating-a-form-builder-in-django-resources) to do this, but you might need to write your own.

Lastly, I wouldn't name the app that holds your user profiles "auth", which could cause a namespace problem with Django's contrib.auth app. I would name it "profiles", just so it's more obvious what that app does and contains.

Hope that gives you some ideas.